# Offsetting polygons by meters with clipper

Tags: python, polygon, coordinates, offset

I would like to create buffered polygons of locations (towns, villages etc) in order to use them for searching in radius.

This is what I would like to achieve (units for ilustration):

[image: Polygon radiuses]

This is how I do it in pyclipper:

```
import pyclipper

coordinates = # Array of lat,lng tuples
clipper_offset = pyclipper.PyclipperOffset()
coordinates = pyclipper.scale_to_clipper(coordinates)
clipper_offset.AddPath(coordinates, pyclipper.JT_ROUND, 
pyclipper.ET_CLOSEDPOLYGON)
scaled_coordinates = clipper_offset.Execute(1000.0)
scaled_coordinates = pyclipper.scale_from_clipper(scaled_coordinates)
```

Number 1000.0 is arbitrary and my question is - **how do I calculate the right offset ratio for Execute method, so that the offset polygon will approximately be offset by 10,20 and 50km ?**

Btw. is this the right approach to this problem ?

Comment: you need to reproject your data into a projection in metres

Comment: So I should project degrees to cartesian in meters ?

Comment: yes, the exact method will vary depending on your tools.

Comment: do you think using WGS84 to convert is fine ?